# Загрузить изображение в input из бд (IFormFile) ASP NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, input

Всем привет.
Есть CRUD система со статьями, у статьи есть фото. Фото загружается в БД и в папку root проекта. При создании статьи все окей, **но при обновлении фото = null**. И по дефолту его нет, то есть пользователю всегда надо будет его загружать. Как сделать так, что бы взять файл из бд и поместить его в этот input?
Конечно можно сделать и по другому, проверять на null и давать путь до загруженной картинки. Возможно, есть решение попроще.

Метод загрузки изображения.

```
        string wwwRoothPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath; //получаем путь до root
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName); //получаем название файла
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName); //получаем разрешение файла
        model.ImageName = filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        string path = Path.Combine(wwwRoothPath + "/Images/", filename);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                model.ImageFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
```

Код формы

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ImageFile">Превью</label>
            <input asp-for="ImageFile" accept="image/*" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ImageFile" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "обновить" - форма будет ругаться, ибо превью обязательно. Проблема в том, что файл не выбран и я не знаю как туда его запихать, допустим из БД. Извиняюсь за "многослов".

[image: Превью]

update. Добавил код метода Update.

```
        //Get метод
        public IActionResult Update(int id)
        {
            var article = _context.Articles.FirstOrDefault(article => article.Id == id);
            return View(article);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(Article model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var oldModel = _context.Articles.FirstOrDefault(article => article.Id == model.Id);

                oldModel.Title = model.Title;
                oldModel.Description = model.Description;

                //Если загружаем новое превью..
                string wwwRoothPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(model.ImageFile.FileName);
                oldModel.ImageName = filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                string path = Path.Combine(wwwRoothPath + "/Images/", filename);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.ImageFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                _context.Articles.Update(oldModel);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Articles));
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: 1. Какая архитектура ASP.NET Core у вас? (MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor-Server). 2. "Есть CRUD система со статьями,..." Где хранятся статьи? в Базе данных? 3. "...у статьи есть фото. Фото загружается в БД и в папку root проекта." Фото хранится в БД, или в папке wwwroot?

Comment: 1)MVC 2) в БД 3)И там и там. в БД просто название файла, в папке root сам файл

Comment: Ок, у Вас реализация CRUD операций, однако код для action-методов, которые собственно их реализуют, отстуствует.  Так вот, для операции Udate, в представлении нужно явно указать что будет вызван метод типа Post,  тогда после нажатия кнопки submit, будет вызван именно метод Update из соответсвующего контроллера. Однако такого кода в вашем представлении я не вижу.

Comment: Вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky), также реализованы CRUD-операции для управления Товарами, и в SQL-базе данных, также хранится только название изображения, а само изображение хранится в специальной подпапке в wwwroot. Проект сделан на ASP.NET Core MVC для .NET 5.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak Спасибо за наводки. Конечно, не до конца понял, о чем Вы говорите. Проблема в том, что когда срабатывает метод  Update типа HttpGet, в представлении нет превью(картинки статьи). Человеку придется постоянно выбирать ее, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы файл был уже выбран и взят он был из БД или из папки root. Добавил код Update в посте, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: CRUD, это аббревиатура от Create- создание, Read (Чтение), Update (Обновление) и Delete(Удаление), и все эти понятия применяются в цепочке Представление-Action метод Контроллера-Сервер Базы Данных,  так вот, когда вы пишите, что у вас проблемы с Обновлением, то Я подразумеваю что, вам нужно заменить файл с картинкой, для той сущности что хранится в БД, но судя по вашему комменту, под словом Обновить, вы подразумеваете Read(Прочесть) данные о ссылке на картинку из Базы Данных, для вашей статьи. Но это разные методы и разные типы HTTP Запросов.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak чуть-чуть пошерудил по Вашему репозиторию, видимо, мою проблему не решить. Сделал по другому. Спасибо за помощь